# Convert a table into flextable in R

Tags: r, flextable

The question is about `R` and the `flextable` package.

This simple R-output

```
> table(mtcars["gear"])

 3  4  5 
15 12  5
```

need to be converted to a `flextable`.

But when I use `flextable()` instead of `table()` each observeration is shown and not the frequency of the 3 possible gears.

It looks like this
[image]

Comment: I'd guess that the package `flextable` is not meant for tabulation ("pivots", frequencies) but for nicely formatted tables to be included in HTML, MS-Word or Powerpoint

Comment: So try `flextable(table(mtcars["gear"]))` instead (just a guess)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert the output of `table()` into a `data.frame` and then you can display it with `flextable`. Flextable is only meant to display something, not to pivot it - as was mentioned in the comments. Try this:

```
flextable(data.frame(table(mtcars["gear"])))
```

[image]

Make sure to read the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flextable/flextable.pdf) of the packages you are using. ;)